# M4A file issue inside Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio

I've tried using this audio file(http://files.parse.com/a2b14059-d5bd-481f-b639-933e80a1667f/480f7428-6067-4a6d-ab8b-b875a94c6b19-audioChat.m4a) in html but I'm having issues getting it to be recognized by Firefox 28. It just flashes and disappears. The interesting thing is if I have like 10-15 different audio tag links on one page, some of them would work while the rest would flash and disappear. By the way, I'm only having these trouble with FF, and not IE or Chrome.

This is one audio tag that does work:

`<audio src="http://files.parse.com/a2b14059-d5bd-481f-b639-933e80a1667f/7ad7b994-1324-4ec1-9963-e4db20971745-audioChat.m4a" controls="controls"  type="audio/mp4">Broken audio!!</audio>`

This is one audio tags that doesn't work.

`<audio src="http://files.parse.com/a2b14059-d5bd-481f-b639-933e80a1667f/480f7428-6067-4a6d-ab8b-b875a94c6b19-audioChat.m4a" controls="controls" type="audio/mp4">Broken audio!!</audio>`

When I try to go to the file directly inside FF, it says the file is corrupt. On Chrome and IE it works fine.

I was just wondering, is the html malformed?

Could it be that FF28 doesn't fully support m4a yet?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

I've checked in here but it does seem like it's full supported (mp4 at least).

I can't seem to tell if this is a FF media licensing issue or if the file is actually corrupted...

Comment: The Mozilla engine dont support `.m4a`. Try to use `.ogg` or `.web`. I had implement a WordPress-Plugin for a long time, if you want to implement  a crossbrowser-player, you need two file formats (`.m4a` and `.ogg` or `.webm`). Add these on your `<audio>`-Tag, the webbrowser decides what format this can play.

Comment: Otherwise, use the **right codec** on your `.m4a` file. If you use the file-encoding `MP4 H.264 (AAC)`, mozilla will be play the `.m4a`.

Comment: How come some renders while some doesn't?

Comment: Either the **codec** from the music-files, else the browser dont support the codec (copyrights).

Comment: @AdrianPreuss [Mozilla **does** support MP4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP4_H.264_(AAC_or_MP3)) on Firefox [for Windows and Linux](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @idbehold than the questioneer use a bad codec.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss [it plays just fine](http://jsbin.com/lufitegi/1/edit) for me in Firefox.

Comment: I don't think I used a bad codec. I recorded these two audios on the same iphone. I would feel if one didn't work. The other one wouldn't work too?

Comment: @idbehold the first audio tag works for you or the second audio tag? The second audio tag doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

So I have attempted to compare the two files using [`ffprobe`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html):

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams broken.m4a
```

The only major differences between the working.m4a and broken.m4a are:

- `stream`:

  - broken.m4a was created 16 years ago.
  - broken.m4a has no `handler_name` in it's `tags`.
- `format`:

  - broken.m4a has a much larger `bit_rate`.
  - broken.m4a has a different `major_brand` and `compatible_brands` in its `tags`

Here is the diff of the two outputs:

[image]

Comment: couldn't figure out why firefox wasn't playing. I used jplayer flash player to play everything instead. That seems to work :)